# How to document.write() a HTML DOM Element Object?

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm trying to get the entire website, and document.write it as a string, but it just turn into a HTML DOM Element Object every time I tried. How do I turn it into a string first?

```
var doc = parser.parseFromString (response.responseText, "text/html");
document.write(doc);
```

Comment: Try using `document.body.innerHTML = doc`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense: document.write parameter must be a string but `doc` is a DOM tree. Simply use response.responseText instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can pull the innerHTML of the `body` element, because this is where `document.write()` will append the text.

```
var doc = document.querySelector("body").innerHTML;
document.write(doc);
```